# Detecting if a WebScriptObject is null

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I'm executing javascript from Cocoa in a WebKit instance. I'm then retrieving an array from the executed script and iterating through it. I know that sometimes one of the items may be null but I am not sure how to check if it's null.

```
id lintObject = [scriptObject valueForKey:@"JSLINT"];

// This is a javascript array                   
WebScriptObject * er = [lintObject valueForKey:@"errors"];

// Cocoa doesn't understand it's an array so we treat it like a JS object                   
NSUInteger count = [[er valueForKey:@"length"] integerValue];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    if ( [er webScriptValueAtIndex:i] == NULL ) {
        // JS array item is null
    } else {
        // item is a JS object
    }

}
```

I know the above test for null won't work but wanted to include it for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing to `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: [NSNull null] didn't do the trick but turns out it was simple as if( ! [er webScriptValueAtIndex:i]) {... The string representation of the null object shows up as (null). Thanks though.